# Printer does not take a job, despite official driver

Tags: drivers, printing

I have a network Epson Stylus Office BX320FW printer: I've already installed the [official driver](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=PT&CN2=&DSCMI=137797&DSCCHK=56f6389310ee88fae930264473d29e8710cc9d2f)

I've tried adding a printer.
These are my only choices:
[image]
Trying to install either of them does not allow me to print documents...

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu version? Exact printer model?

Comment: @user68186 I added the information. ;)

Comment: @brian_p I added the information ;)